# How do I transfer and replicate all the contents of a function into an array from the function itself?

Tags: javascript

So to be very clear. I want the execution of the function to cause the function itself to be added into the array. I want the function to be transferred over to the array ***from within the function.***.

Example:

```
 emptyArray = []       //All functions will be sent here.

var transferFunction = function() {
    alert("I want to be sent to emptyArray from  
    within the function itself. How do I do that?  
    I don't want to use emptyArray[0] = transferFunction;
    What I want, is for transferFunction to replicate
    itself, and be sent to the empty array.
    Can anyone answer how to do this?");
}
```

Comment: `emptyArray.push(transferFunction)`

Comment: adeneo, you are still calling the array first. What code can I use to do this without using "emptyArray" at all, but by doing it within the transferFunction itself?

Comment: You can't, how would you put a function inside an array without ever referencing the array, or even having an array.

Comment: @ironSteel can you clarify your question because right now it doesn't really make much sense. What do you mean by being "sent to" the `emptyArray` variable?

Comment: That is fine if you reference the array inside of the function. But I need to have the function send itself to the array as part of that function's instructions. I can't assign the function to the array outside of the function, it has to be within the function itself.

Comment: This sounds more and more as an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you describe what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @vlaz Sorry if my terminology is off, but I want transferFunction to become a part of emptyArray's index. I want the commands for this to happen from within the transferFunction itself. That is what I mean by being "Sent" over to emptyArray[] is that understandable?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, when you call `transferFunction()` you want the contents of `emptyArray` to become `[ transferFunction ]` _without_ using any explicit references to `emptyArray` inside the function? And again, _why_ do you want to do this, what is the concrete problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: @vlaz That is correct. You understand what I am trying to do. The reason I want to do this, is because I have many functions that need to be put inside of emptyArray[] and I wanted to do this with as little code as possible, without referencing emptyArray[] at all if possible. I want each function to have the appropriate instructions so that they are automatically sent to emptyArray[] without me having to type the commands outside of the function itself. This would save me time and code space.

Comment: @ironSteel What does having the functions' references shoved inside an array achieve?  Granted that I haven't seen your code base, but this, as well as what you describe, sounds unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Why not just have a higher order function `transfer(f) { emptyArray.push(f) }` then just call `transfer(function1); transfer(function2);`. Then again, the functions being _in_ the array seems like a really odd choice - are you going to do `emptyArray.forEach( f => f())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to do something like this?

```js
var transferFunction = (function(arr){
    var _id = 10;
    var _fn = function(name) { console.log("Hi " + name); };
    return (arr[_id] = _fn);
})(window.emptyArray || (window.emptyArray = []));

// should log "Hi Sue"
transferFunction("Sue");

// should log "Hi Sam"
window.emptyArray[10]("Sam");
```

Comment: Yes that is closer to what I am trying to do.  I tested it using: myFunctions[0](); and I was able to run your function. Now, do you know how I could put each function into a specific index inside of the myFunctions array?

Comment: In anticipation of this I updated the code to take set an index rather than use **push** I have also updated the variables to reflect those from your original post.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo says in his comment above:

```
var emptyArray = []
var transferFunction = function() {
    emptyArray.push(transferFunction)
}
```

will work.

The bigger question is *why* you want to do this.

***EDIT***

If you want a "centralized" object to hold functions, use a JavaScript object:

```
var functions = {
    func1: function () {},
    func2: function () {},
    ...
}
```

Then invoke the functions by accessing the objects properties:

```
functions.func1()
```

The only reason you would want an array is if you intend to invoke the functions in a `for` loop.

Comment: The reason I want to do this, is suppose I have 50 functions that need to be put inside of emptyArray[], instead of going one by one emptyArray[0] = transferFunction and so on, I'd rather send each of these 50 functions to the emptyArray[] with the commands to do so inside of each function.

Comment: So you're rather modify 50 functions to do that one thing?

Comment: May I ask what you intend to do with the array once the 50 functions have been added to it? I've never encountered a problem that would benefit from this sort of pattern and I'd be interested to learn more.

Comment: The array itself would become a function hub. Each index would represent a particular function. With an index given to each function, the array itself becomes the mastermind of all the functions.

Comment: @vlaz "So you're rather modify 50 functions to do that one thing?" Do you know of an easier way to accomplish this? If I have each function be sent to the array, I find that easier than explicitly stating each index outside of the functions themselves.

Comment: Have you thought about the fact that you'll have to invoke all the functions to get them into the array in the first place? And that each time they are invoked they will get added to the array again? Also you'll have to have some way of knowing which index maps to which function. I would only do this if your main use case for the array is using it in a `for` loop. Otherwise you should look into using an object with functions as properties if you want that kind of functionality.

Comment: @ironSteel that sounds like absolutely terrible idea. Functions already have names which is how you call them. You want to replace that with some arbitrary numbers so instead of calling `add(2, 3)` you will call `functions[17](2, 3)`

Comment: @bmceldowney Those are things I did not think about. I would like to use a for loop with all the functions inside of the array. I also need to figure out how to assign each function to a particular index.

Comment: @vlaz I find it easier to memorize numbers of an index inside of an array, rather than the function names themselves. I also would think this is more organized. If I use an object to store all the functions, then I cannot use a for loop.

Comment: @ironSteel  You will be fine if you get it working with what you are doing.  Just make sure to comment that it needs to be revisited taking the criticisms made above.  Maybe you can figure out, as your project goes along, why there may be a better way.  I think everyone learning needs to go through this a few times as they learn how to organize things effectively.

Comment: You shouldn't really have to "memorize" function names, they should be named in such a way that they are self-explanatory.